# Escaping character from Windows to WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, quotation-marks

I am trying to send the following line :

```
trap 'test -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" && eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k`' 0
```

to a file from Windows to WSL.

Here is what I've got so far :

```
bash -c "echo -e 'trap test -n \"\$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\" && eval \`/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k\` 0'  >> $HOME/test"
```

I can't find a way to quote the trap argument. Thanks in advence for your help.

Comment: WSL and Windows are on the same server. Can't you edit the file directly or at least remove the `bash -c` and call `echo` directly?

Comment: @WalterA That's what I did at first (using ifstream/c++) but the created file have messed up rights & owner and chmod doesn't seem to fix it. And according to Rich Turner [it is not recommended to so](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: Off-topic,  Get used to: 1. curly braces like `${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}`. 2. call subcommands with `$(some_comand)`, avoiding problems with escaping or nesting backtics. 3. Dont call a file `test`, that is a shell command!

Comment: I don't understand all remarks of Rich, most problems seem to be with symbolic links. Perhaps sending the file to a fixed path like `C:\transfer\mytrap.sh` will work better. Maybe also possible from ifstream/c++.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found a solution : use a fonction

```
bash -c "echo -e 'onexit() { test -n \"\$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\" && eval \`/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k\`; }' > $HOME/testA"
bash -c "echo -e trap onexit 0  >> $HOME/testA"
```